# Why we cannot populate a non-static collection outside of a method?

Tags: java, collections

I accidently wrote this code and found errors:

```
class Main {
    LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
    list.add(10);
    list.add(5);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main myObj = new Main();
        System.out.prinln(myObj.list);
    }
}
```

If I am declaring LinkedList as static and populating it static block there is no error or if I am creating a method and then populating the list inside method then also there is no error.

I am a beginner and not able to understand the reason why it is not being populated when I am trying as in the given above code. Please explain it as for 1st standard student.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you want it to be populated when the `Main` object gets created (`new Main()`)? if so, add those lines in the _constructor_.

Answer (score 3):

If we break down the code above, it is composed of a `class` named "Main" containing:

- A `variable` named "list" of type LinkedList
- A statement `list.add(10);`
- Another statement `list.add(5);`
- A method named "main" containing another 2 statements.

A `class` in java is a language construct that is allowed to have certain kinds of members.

The java specs tell us what members a class is allowed to have:

> The body of a class declares members (fields, methods, classes, and interfaces), instance and static initializers, and constructors

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.2

The issue with the above code is that statements are not allowed to be members of a class. The compiler will reject those.

Java does however give us a tool to populate a collection outside of a method. <s>This is static initializers</s>

*Edit: Thanks to @Ole V.V. and @fps for correcting me here*

This is an instance initializer

> An instance initializer declared in a class is executed when an instance of the class is created

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.6

Applied to the above code we can write:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

class Main {
    LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
    { // This bracket starts the initializer 
        list.add(10);
        list.add(5);
    } // This bracket closes the initializer
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main myObj = new Main();
        System.out.println(myObj.list);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps a little :)

Comment: That's an instance initializer, as @OleV.V. is saying. Static initializers are used to initialize class variables, and a class variable is a static variable, class variable is just another way to call a static variable. Instance initializers, on the other hand, are useful to initialize instance fields, such as the LinkedList of the question (i.e. non static members)

Comment: Apart from this little confusion about static vs non static initializers, your answer is excellent

Comment: Oh, I'd been getting that wrong all this time :) Thanks both for clarifying that!

Answer (score 3):

> … the reason why it is not being populated when I am trying as in the
> given above code.

Because the Java language was designed that way. `list.add(10)` is a method call, and there are restrictions on where method calls are allowed. It would be perfectly possible to design a language that allowed method calls (and other statements) interleaved with declarations in a class. I have not seen it in any language, though. It might also get confusing in the end.

Allow two suggestions:

1. Think twice before using a `LinkedList`.
2. Populate your list in the declaration.

In my 20+ years as a Java programmer I *once* used a `LinkedList` and in retrospect regretted. That class has so few good uses. `ArrayList` will nearly always be more efficient in terms of time and space.

Since Java 9 you may declare and populate the list in this way if it doesn’t need to be modifiable:

```
List<Integer> list = List.of(10, 5);
```

If you do need to be able to modify the list later:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(List.of(10, 5));
```

The same works for `LinkedList`, BTW. In Java 8 and earlier you may use `Arrays.asList()`, for example:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(10, 5));
```